# Rest API Hook When Post Is Requested

Tags: hooks, rest-api

I am aware that I can use the endpoint `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/{id}` to fetch a post.

I am building an implementation of WordPress that relies completely on the JSON API and its endpoints. It is an Angular SPA implementation, which means my hooks need to fire when a request is made via the API.

As such, if I want to record views for a post, I wanted to use [`'posts_selection'`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/posts_selection). My first question is will this fire if the selection is made via `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/{id}`

My second question is is there another hook or something that will also fire during API query for a post but which will pass the `{id}` of the post to my function?

Because when I do this:

```
function check_assembled_query( $query ) {
    var_dump( $query );
}

 add_action( 'posts_selection', 'check_assembled_query' );
```

`$query` doesn't have the information I want. I would like the following workflow:

1. Request a post using `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/{id}` from AngularJS.
2. Have the backend recognize this request and iterate a meta field of the post's views using [`update_post_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) which requires a post `id`.
3. Return the post requested to my JavaScript function with all the post's information, including aforementioned meta-info view-count.

**EDIT:** I take it `post_selection` doesn't fire for REST API because when I do this:

```
function check_assembled_query( $query ) {
    var_dump( $query );
    die();
}

 add_action( 'posts_selection', 'check_assembled_query' );
```

I only get the dump on regular requests rather than requests to the JSON API.

Comment: It is better to use it https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_field/
So you get full control over your field in response of the REST server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My original answer was all wrong, so it's been removed in it's entirety.

Neither the `posts_selection` nor `wp` hook are fired during the REST API request.

The hook you need is `rest_pre_echo_response`. This hook passes three parameters:

1. The response data to send to the client
2. The server instance.
3. The request used to generate the response.

Since you need the post ID, you can do something like:

```
add_filter( 'rest_pre_echo_response', function( $response, $object, $request ) {
  //* Get the post ID
  $post_id = $response[ 'id' ];

  //* Make sure of the post_type
  if( 'post' !== $response[ 'post' ] ) return $response;

  //* Do something with the post ID

  //* Return the new response
  return $response;
}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, I should use this umbrella hook and then check for conditions, such as a post request? Why does the `posts_selection` fire for REST if it doesn't kill the response when I employ `die()`?

Comment: updating my answer since it's wrong. oops.

Comment: Another question, how do I filter the `wp` hook for a `is_post()` type of conditional?

Comment: `is_single()` doesn't fire on the Rest endpoint for posts?

Comment: oh dear... i can't find documentation for that hook, just source code. And it suggests that I'd have to do some kind of filtering to make sure the `$response` is actually of `type:'post'` correct?

Comment: is_post() isn't an actual WordPress function, so not sure. is_single doesn't appear to work. :-/. you can get the post type from the response array. $response[ 'type' ].

Comment: last question, what does `10, 3 )` do in the closue?

Comment: 10 is the hook priority, and 3 is the number of parameters passed to the callback.

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting a 2 years old question, but can you add an action to a filter hook? Shouldn't it be add_filter?

Comment: Can you? Yes. Should you? No. Shouldn't it be add_filter? Yes. Thanks.

Comment: filter need to return something, in this case the $response object - so, ```if( 'post' !== $response[ 'post' ] ) return $response;```