# Modify WordPress Rest Api Request/Response

Tags: filters, hooks, rest-api

I am building an application using WordPress Rest API.

I want to make simple calls to the API, such as just **`/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`** and let the backend have a systematic way how to handle this and serve `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=7` under the hood instead.

Basically, how can I override the defaults for the Rest API responses without specifying them in the query string?

Again, I don't want to pass parameters in the query string. I need *simple query strings* and *standardized response*s.

This: [WordPress Docs - Modifying Responses](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/) doesn't seem to cover my use case, it is to add fields and the like, which is not what I want to do. I'm looking for a way to hook into the request and alter it before returning a response.

So something a little before this hook: [Rest API Hook When Post Is Requested](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/286307/rest-api-hook-when-post-is-requested) perhaps?

I gather that the above hook has already gotten ready to serve the response, I want to hook in *before that* to change the request headers.

**EDIT:**

The closest filter I have found is : [this one](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_request_from_url/) but it never seems to fire.

Furthermore, [rest_pre_dispatch](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_pre_dispatch/) is filtering the response, not the request.

Is there nothing like [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/request) for the Rest API?

If so, how do I alter the response without slowing down my server, since it will fetch 10 posts by default before I chop it down to however many I actually want.

Answer (score 4):

I think I found answer to your question, it is: `rest_{$this->post_type}_query`  filter hook. With this hook you are able to directly edit internal WP_Query parameter.

For example, if you'd like to internally sort Posts by `post_title` by default, then you'd have to write something like this:

```
function order_rest_post_by_post_title($args, $request) {
  $args['orderby'] = 'post_title';
  $args['order'] = 'DESC';

  return $args;
}
add_filter('rest_post_query', 'order_rest_post_by_post_title', 10, 2);
```

For more info please follow [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_this-post_type_query/) link.

Answer (score 0):

To define default values, you can use the filter `rest_{$post_type}_collection_params` like that :

```
$post_type = "post";

add_filter("rest_{$post_type}_collection_params", function ($query_params, $post_type) {

    $query_params["per_page"]["default"] = 7;

    return $query_params;

}, 10, 2);
```

Comment: Do you think it would be better, if I don't want default routes anyway, to just disable the default and return my own custom endpoints that return exactly what I want?